Create OVS queues - Parent's Queue burst can't be updated
I am creating this QoS with OVS. I replace intf, max, and min on run time
ovs-vsctl -- set port {intf} qos=@newqos -- --id=@newqos create qos type=linux-htb \
  other-config:burst=1280000 other-config:max-rate={max} queues=0=@q0,1=@q1 \
  -- --id=@q0 create queue other-config:burst=1280000 other_config:priority=2 other-config:max-rate={max} other-config:min-rate={min} \
  -- --id=@q1 create queue other-config:burst=1280000 other_config:priority=1 other-config:max-rate={max} other-config:min-rate={min}


The issue is that this will create weird configs
class htb 1:1 parent 1:fffe prio 2 rate 500Mbit ceil 1Gbit burst 160000b cburst 160000b 
class htb 1:fffe root rate 1Gbit ceil 1Gbit burst 1375b cburst 1375b 
class htb 1:2 parent 1:fffe prio 1 rate 500Mbit ceil 1Gbit burst 160000b cburst 160000b 

Notice how the parent's queue has smaller burst and cburst values. I tried too many commands but I wasn't able to change this behavior.
I tried to update the burst and cburst of the parent queue  later on with this command
sudo tc class replace dev as1-eth2 parent 1: classid 1:fffe htb rate {min} ceil {max} burst 160000 cburst 160000

It works!! But after a few minutes it will go back to the old value!
How to oercome this issue?
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS"
---------------------
$ uname -r
6.8.0-49-generic
--------------------------
$ ovs-vsctl --version
(Open vSwitch) 3.3.3
DB Schema 8.5.0 

Best

Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic
ovs-vsctl (Open vSwitch) 3.3.3
DB Schema 8.5.0
